# I can't open a source file while the source file location is changed in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, file, linker, project, visual-studio-2019

I am currently going through Visual Studio 2019 and I face a problem:

[image: image of my error]

The problem is that I deleted the "test linking" folder mentioned in the picture, and then cleaned the solution and hit the build button.

I moved the `linktest.cpp` file to another folder, but the `.cpp` file is still being searched for in the removed folder, and of course I get the error that the file could not be found.

Could anyone tell me in detail what is happening that I am facing this issue, and what I should do to fix it?

Comment: remove `linktest.cpp` from your project and the compiler will stop trying to compile it

Comment: thank Alen i know this kind of approach but i want something deeper

Comment: You're asking the compiler to compile a file that doesn't exist, what deeper explanation do you want?

Comment: the file exsist but i just moved it alan..... look i did this :: the cpp file was in a directory .i removed the directory and moved the cpp file to another directory so if you look at the image a blue lock came beside my file when i did this it's my question that is there any setting to do which the cpp file again could be compiled do you get me?

Comment: yes, remove the old file and add the new one, there is no way for visual studio to know where your file has been moved to

Comment: thank you so much Alan thank you for your help can i have more intraction with you to ask my questions?

Comment: You can ask a new question